# Is it possible to use web inspector on XCode's iPhone emulator?

Tags: mobile-safari

I have an issue that happens only on iPhone (not Safari desktop) and need to inspect the HTML code for a page. On an actual iPhone, I can go to Settings > Safari > Advanced > "Web Inspector", but if I do the same thing on the emulator, there is no such thing as "Web Inspector".

[image]

Do I need to use a real iPhone if I want to use the Web Inspector, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Web Inspector is always available on Simulator — there is no toggle, but empirically it can be considered to always be on. Safari sees all simulators in its Develop menu.

Comment: Thanks, that is what it says on https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650901 also, however, it is not clear to me how to find the simulator in Safari's Develop menu. If I go to the develop menu on Desktop Safari, there is no "Simulator" item, so I do not know what to select.

Comment: It should appear near the top of the Develop menu, as a device you can select